# Modal box in WordPress with bootstrap is unable to open videos on same link

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on WordPress with bootstrap theme. I'm using modal box to open videos on my page .my problem is that I want to open two differnt videos on same link is it possible? Means once I click on that link one video will appear and on another click the other will apear on modal box.

Here is my code for modal box:

```
<div id="myModal1" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-body">
<button type="button" class="close well" data-dismiss="modal">×</button><br />
    <iframe width="480" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/tgOFI5xAKU0?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>​
```

And here is the link from where I m clicking:

```
<li class="span3"><a data-target="#myModal1" data-toggle="modal" href=""><img src="my image url" alt="" /></a>
<div class="image_caption">Faculty Speak &gt;&gt;</div></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue that you will run into is how will the modal know what to display and when.  I think there are some UX issues with this approach.  Below are a couple examples.

1. What happens if a user clicks the link a 3rd time?
2. How does the user know they need to click the link again?
3. What happens if they accidentally close the modal? Can they get back to the video they were watching or does it open the next one?

You could easily add a second link that opens a second modal.  Just duplicate your existing modal and change it's id to "myModal2"